# return value of the key stored in a json by passing the key name dynamically from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have am getting some value which I am storing in a variable. I also have a json which has that value as one of the keys. Now I am trying to return the value stored in that key by passing the value stored in the variable. What I am doing def doesn't work and it makes sense that it does not. But the question is how would I achieve it by using pure javascript?

```
var x = 'john' 
var jsonObj = {"john": 10, "paul": 20}

console.log(jsonObj.x)
```

Comment: `jsonObj[x]` ??

Comment: @RudieVisser -- yes it is. That was easy and I couldn't think of it

Comment: Don't worry about it, once you've faced the problem you won't forget it anymore ;)